# How to rewrite Groovy gradle task to Kotlin gradle scripts

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have these two gradle tasks written in groovy and I can't find a proper way how to rewrite them to Kotlin:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}


task clearAppCache(type: Exec) {
    def clearDataCommand = ['adb', 'shell', 'pm', 'clear', 'io.hruska.pocketplay']
    commandLine clearDataCommand
}
```

I am especially not sure about how to replace the "commandLine" method and how to add a "type:Exec" argument to task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the following should do the trick:

```
tasks {

    // will need to import KotlinCompile or use the fully qualified name
    withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    register<Exec>("clearAppCache") {
        commandLine = listOf("adb", "shell", "pm", "clear", "io.hrushka.pocketplay")
    }

}
```

Some links:

- [Writing Custom Gradle Tasks](https://guides.gradle.org/writing-gradle-tasks/)<sup>1</sup>
- [Gradle Kotlin DSL Primer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html)

---

<sup>1. Switch the example code blocks from Groovy to Kotlin.</sup>